# Make a div appear when scrolling past a certain point of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

My goal is to make a fixed div appear at the top of a page once someone scrolls a certain amount of pixels down the page.  Basically once the header section is out of view, this div will appear.

I've looked at code similar to what I want; however, haven't seen anything that would allow me to easily modify the pixel count from the top of the page (if possible).

Here is a piece of code I saw dealing with making divs appear by scrolling.

```
// Get the headers position from the top of the page, plus its own height
var startY = $('header').position().top + $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
});

function checkY(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
        $('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
    }
}

// Do this on load just in case the user starts half way down the page
checkY();
```

I just want to know how to make it appear.  If someone knows of a piece of code already in tact with a slide up and slide down animation, that would be greatly appreciated as well but not required.

Comment: In the example you gave, `$('.fixedDiv').slideDown()` is making the div appear. Is that code not working for you? Here is a jsFiddle using exactly that code: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Ehney/

Comment: I haven't tried it because I don't know how to modify it to appear once the person scrolls past 500px from the top.  Thats the main thing I need.

Comment: You would change the first line, with the `startY`, to be the specific Y position you need, rather than calculating based on the header's position and height. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Ehney/1/

Comment: I went to the site you said to find the code at, copied everything out....inserted everything between css stylesheet and html index.php page and couldn't get it to work.  It worked on the page you showed me, and I copied everything word for word but can't get it to work.  Any idea why?

Comment: Do you see any errors on your browser JavaScript console?

Comment: it says that there is an illegal character for line 
checkY();​

Comment: Not sure what to tell you--perhaps there is an error elsewhere on the page that is causing the JavaScript to parse weird? As you can see, the code works, so it has to be something related to your particular setup.

Comment: I don't get what it could be as I'm testing this as a standalone site for this code...thats it..nothing else is on the site...oh well, I'll keep trying.

Comment: found the issue. When I copied and pasted the javascript code, a weird character was inserted after that line and it caused the entire script to mess up.  It showed up as a space (no character) even thuugh the character was actually being created...Your code works like a charm!  Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function() { 
   if(window.scrollY > 500) {
      $('.fixedDiv').slideDown();
   }
   else {
      $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();
   }
},false);
```

Comment: Error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined....          $('.fixedDiv').slideDown(); and $('.fixedDiv').slideUp();

Comment: A possible improvement would be not to bind to the scroll event, but instead use setInterval to check the current scroll position at regular intervals. That way the handle isn't fired every time when scrolling, which could lead to bad performance. Another way would be to bind to scroll, but only fire the method again after a certain interval. Some examples of how to implement this pattern: https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-patterns/window-scroll-event.html. This is also mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591002/jquery-setinterval-or-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Brandon Tilley answered my question in a comment...

> You would change the first line, with the startY, to be the specific Y
>   position you need, rather than calculating based on the header's
>   position and height. Here's an updated fiddle:
>   jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/Ehney/1

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function() { 
   $('.fixedDiv')[(window.scrollY > 500)?"slideDown":"slideUp"]();
},false);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8eG2A/

Comment: Error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined.... same as the previous example lostsource gave me

Comment: @kdjernigan - `$` should be defined because it is refering to `jQuery`. See my demo, it is working.