# jquery setInterval or scroll

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization

I am working on a project where i need to listen to the `scroll` event.. i wonder what is a better approach..

## 1st Approach

```
 function scroll() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        top.fadeIn();
    } else {
        top.fadeOut();
    }
    if (menuVisible) {
      quickHideMenu();
    }
}
```

## 2nd Approach

```
      function scroll() {
          didScroll = true;
      }

      setInterval(function() {
          if ( didScroll ) {
              didScroll = false;
              if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
                  top.fadeIn();
              } else {
                  top.fadeOut();
              }
              if (menuVisible) {
                quickHideMenu();
              }
          }
      }, 250);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/   read this article by the creator of twitter John Resig

Comment: @MohammadAdil I have read it and that is what made me think about this question..

Comment: @LuckySoni What did you end up doing?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't remember what I used back then but today I would use whatever suits my needs. I think both the 2nd approach in my question and the accepted answer are equally good but they are fundamentally different. One uses throttling and the other applies debouncing. The selection of solution should depend on what you want to do. See the difference here http://demo.nimius.net/debounce_throttle. Sorry, I am answering your question years after you asked it but I am glad that I have a better answer now.

Comment: I asked that in 2013 - I have no idea why I asked :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Neither. I was just reading about JS/jQuery patterns. There is an example for the Window Scroll event: [jQuery Window Scroll Pattern](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-patterns/window-scroll-event.html)

```
var scrollTimeout;  // global for any pending scrollTimeout

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (scrollTimeout) {
        // clear the timeout, if one is pending
        clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
        scrollTimeout = null;
    }
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(scrollHandler, 250);
});

scrollHandler = function () {
    // Check your page position
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
        top.fadeIn();
    } else {
        top.fadeOut();
    }
    if (menuVisible) {
        quickHideMenu();
    }
};
```

Originally from here: [Javascript Patterns](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/)

Comment: That Javascript Patterns library is gold!

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me

```
<style type="text/css">
    .scrollToTop {
        width:100px; 
        height:130px;
        padding:10px; 
        text-align:center; 
        background: whiteSmoke;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #444;
        text-decoration: none;
        position:fixed;
        top:75px;
        right:40px;
        display:none;
        background: url('arrow_up.png') no-repeat 0px 20px;
    }

.scrollToTop:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>

<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Scroll To Top</a>
```

http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-an-animated-scroll-to-top-with-jquery

Comment: Is it fine to not check if the fadeIn() method has already been applied to the element ?