# Fixed row/column header with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, scroll

I need a layout with fixed column/row header. After some "trial and error" I came up with this solution (see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mich24/kkpq60d9/)). Only the lower right pane is scrollable, and the headers are moved using javascript.

Everything is fine in Chrome, but in IE/Edge the scrolling is laggy: the left and the right part are not scrolled on the same time but with a minimal delay (especially it the content is "big") which is annoying. Do you see any solution? I have to find another way to achieve the result (and in this case do you have any suggestion)?

```js
$(function() {
    init();

});

function init(){
    var div1=$("#mainContainer");
    
    var oldScrollTop = $(div1).scrollTop();

    $(div1)
        .scroll( function () {
            if (oldScrollTop == $(div1).scrollTop()){
                scrollRowTableHeader(); //horizontal scroll
            }else {
                oldScrollTop = $(div1).scrollTop();
                scrollColumnTableHeader(); //vertical scroll
            }
        });

}

function scrollColumnTableHeader() {

    var vScrollPanel = $("#mainContainer"),
        headerPanelContent = $("#headerPanelContent"),
        colHeaderPanelContent = $("#colHeaderPanelContent");

    var colHeaderPanelContent2 = document.getElementById('headerContent');

    colHeaderPanelContent2.style.top = (0 - vScrollPanel.scrollTop())+"px";

};

function scrollRowTableHeader() {

    var vScrollPanel = $("#mainContainer"),
        headerPanelContent = $("#headerPanelContent"),
        colHeaderPanel = $("#colHeaderPanel");

    var headerPanelContent2 = document.getElementById('headerPanelContent');

    headerPanelContent2.style.left = (0 - vScrollPanel.scrollLeft())+"px";

};
```

```css
#container {
    /*background-color: green;*/
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.bigContent{
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.scroll{
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}

.colheader{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  /*position: relative;*/
  z-index: 1;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: inline;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.headerContent{
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.rowHeaderContent{
  background: whitesmoke;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.rowColHeaderContent{
  background: lightyellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.headerPanel{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.tableProperties{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">
    <div class="rowColHeaderContent">
        <table class="tableProperties">
          <tr><td>Row/Col Header</td></tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="headerPanel" class="headerPanel">
      <div id="headerPanelContent" class="rowHeaderContent">
         <table width="500px" class="tableProperties">
         <colgroup><col width="50"><col width="40"><col width="40"><col width="40"><col width="45"><col width="40"></colgroup>
            <tr><td>Some content (header)</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>


<div id="container">
  <div id="colheader" class="colheader">
    <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
        <table width="500px" class="tableProperties">
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Column Header</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div id="mainContainer" class="item scroll">
      <div class="bigContent">
         <table width="500px" class="tableProperties">
         <colgroup><col width="50"><col width="40"><col width="40"><col width="40"><col width="45"><col width="40"></colgroup>
            <tr><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td><td>Some content</td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this is not a direct answer to your *really complex* issue, but here goes..

First of all looks like you are in the first steps of trying to create a fixed-column and fixed-row table. It might seem to be working at first, but, trust me, the way you are trying to achieve it is not going to work well and the reason is that since table-cell widths are set arbitrarily for **each** table, you won't be able to align the *header* table with the *content* table below it. So, you will either have to follow a different approach than the current way you are taking - tips imminent.

First things first, the problem with *a lot of data* in this kind of situation is more noticeable in IE11 - the lag is lighter in IE edge and there is no lag in other browsers. In your case you can use **debouncing** in order to reduce the js calls while scrolling.

```
setInterval(function(){                 
  // Scroll stuff here
}, 2)
```

The interval doesn't have to be high, a *light* lag will be visible, but it will be a great improvement compared to how (I suppose) it currently works.

Also try using Javascript functions that work with minimum impact, eg use `.attr`  instead of `.style`; also try using CSS3 transforms instead of normal transforms.

So concerning the different approach - you have to *somehow* the scrolling header and content be in the same table - ideally the fixed column as well. Here are some tips. It is necessary to remove word wrapping within the table cells by using `white-space:nowrap` for the following tips to work as intended. The concept might be difficult to grasp, but once you encounter each issue they will make sense.

First of all add some top padding to the table that will accommodate the header elements described next. Create both `p` and `span` elements inside the header cells and place the same header content in both of them. Absolutely position the `span` elements using CSS3 transforms towards the top.

The 'p' elements will remain static, but not visible - hide them using `visibility`, `opacity` and `height:0`. Paragraph elements will be used in case the `th` content exceeds the `td` content.

In order to scroll everything with decent performance you will HAVE to use CSS3 transforms to scroll the `span` elements (careful: the `span` elements!) after you cache them on page load.

Hope these tips help you out, for any questions feel free to ask - it will be difficult to digest at first but it will make sense.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Fixed cols is not a problem, I can achieve it setting table-layout fixed and <colgroup> (I have updated the script). Fixed rows IS indeed a problem. At the moment I have a JS function that set the same height for the left and right table (maybe not best practice, but it work).

Comment: The problem with the scroll events in IE/Edge is that I get too few events (and therefore the div is moved with a little delay), if I use setInterval(...) the problem is emphasized. I'll check the hints for the alternative approach, thx.

Comment: ...what you are saying is not valid - actually the exact opposite happens; actually what is happening is that when you are scrolling there are TOO MANY events, one on top of the other and the browser engine can't handle it, so it skips frames. Try my solution and report back. I am telling you because I had the same issue in a similar table-solution.

Comment: I have tried in this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591002/jquery-setinterval-or-scroll an believe me, it is worse (in Chrome too). The left panel is updated after a bigger delay (which seems reasonable to me). I'm doing something wrong? Uhm... wait a moment.... is not exactly what you have said... I check again sorry...

Comment: In this way? https://jsfiddle.net/Mich24/wsot9ar5/ (just check JS code). I can confirm it's worse...

Comment: ...as I said, you need to cache the elements on page load. Now you are forcing the browser to search all the dom tree to find your elements inside your scrolling function. Take your variables and cache them OUTSIDE the functions. Other than that it seems that you get the idea, as soon as you see it working properly it will make sense - however, I can't say in the blind.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want Only the lower right pane is scrollable?
- I just used css like :-

  .headerContent{
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 200px;
    position: static;
    border: solid 1px;
  }
- Changed `position: relative into static`...

Comment: The row column should scroll too when scrolling horizontally, the column header should scroll too when scrolling vertically