# Javascript to make div appear after scroll is showing on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I input this code (which I pulled from this answer: [Make a div appear when scrolling past a certain point of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549214/make-a-div-appear-when-scrolling-past-a-certain-point-of-a-page)) to make a div appear when the user scrolls down on the page.

The problem is:  The div appears as soon as the page loads, and disappears when the user scrolls, and then reappears when they scroll > 700.

How do I get the div to not show up at the beginning of the page load?

Thanks!

```
<script>
// Get the headers position from the top of the page, plus its own height
var startY = 700;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkY();
});

function checkY(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
        $('.scroll-up').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.scroll-up').slideUp();
    }
}

// Do this on load just in case the user starts half way down the page
checkY();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS set `display:none` property for the div you don't want to show on page load

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **slideUp()** and **slideDown()**
you can use, **fadeIn()** and **fadeOut()** or **slidetoggle()**;